# Laravel no logout option from menu after successfull login

Tags: php, authentication, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, navbar

Hope anyone else had the same issue and was able to solve this problem.
I installed a fresh Laravel project and used **php artisan make:auth** to get the basic auth working. Strange thing is that after a successful login there is no logout link in the navbar. It should be available under the username (which has a pull down option) but when I click on my username nothing happens.

Anyone has a solution? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: If no logout option available, then why dont you add it by yourself?

Comment: @Qazi well .. it is there but it's not working. Therefore my Q

Comment: please share your code for logout button, also check that Does logout Route and method is available ?

Comment: @Qazi: See code below.

Comment: why is this stil not fixed in laravel 7 but next to that this answer isn't working for me and i have no clue why

if fixed it by forgeting to add the js part of the bootstrap but weird bootstrap is not standard in the laravel package if it is being used so mutch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved:

Seems like Laravel is not loading the right JQuery files to make it work.
Be sure to load the right JQuery libs like these:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is a while since the question was answered, but I thought the following information might be as useful to someone as it was to me...

If you have used npm's SASS compiler, Webpack will have condensed all of the CSS into app.css and all of the Javascript into app.js. The app.js includes all of the Javascript from Bootstrap, so including the Bootstrap js separately seems to break the dropdown menus.

I found that removing my own references to the Bootstrap js files and making sure I had:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

at the end of my layouts.app file, worked like a charm. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: why doesn't this work for me then i am not susing the sass compiler but it stil doesn't work for me and when i add the bootstrap link myself it does work but the js broke

FIXED added the js files from bootstrap and it works now

Answer (score 1):

@Qazi: It's just the standard app.blade.php from Laravel itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    &nbsp;
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                        onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        Logout
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    @include ('layouts.partials._notifications')

    @yield('content')
</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Then this is my web.php in routes folder:

```
<?php

Use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
    return view('home');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/activate/token/{token}', 'Auth\ActivationController@activate')->name('auth.activate');
Route::get('/activate/resend', 'Auth\ActivationController@resend')->name('auth.activate.resend');
```

Now what I did notice is that the css markup is not there when I switch pages. Eg if I click on the 'forgot password' link, the css markup is gone. Seems like it can't find the css folder or the path is not right on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by simply removing JQuery and Bootstrap scripts, as they are loaded by app.js (I'm using laravel 5.5).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the script that i had added loading popper.js from a cdn. After i deleted that line the dropdown loaded.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

add bootstrap link : `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score -2):

It's working for me after using these commands

npm install

npm run dev